# Why in the file smb.conf before parameter names spaces are used

Tags: linux, samba

I can't understand why in the file `/etc/samba/smb.conf` leading spaces are used in parameter names, while in `man smb.conf` stated "Leading, trailing and internal whitespace in section and parameter names is irrelevant."

For example, default settings:

```
[printers]
   comment = All Printers
   browseable = no
```

Three spaces before the word "comment"

Answer (score 0):

This is done for readability, just like whitespace is used in programming languages like C: you can immediately see that the `comment` belongs to the section `printers`.

Comment: Thanks. I am, it turns out, incorrectly translated the word irrelevant, and thought that Leading, trailing and internal whitespace are prohibited =)